# Creating UILocalNotifications with CoreData attribute

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

In my iOS app I am trying to create a `localNotification` to notify the user 15 minutes prior to the event beginning. However I am stuck. I am using `CoreData` to store data. I have an `Appointment` object which can be created. A `date` attribute is associated with a `Appointment` object. I am really stuck with it. I do not know how to set up the `timeInterval` and the rest of the notification process.

I do not know how to set up the `timeInterval` from the time the `Appointment` is created to 15 minutes prior to when it begins.

Here is some of my code:

```
func scheduleNotifications() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    guard let client = client, let name = client.name, let formula = formula, let date = formula.date else { return }
    content.title = "BookMe"
    content.subtitle = ""
    content.body = "Your appointment with \(name) will begin soon."
    content.badge = 1

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: ??, repeats: false)
```

Edited: This is what I have but nothing is firing.

```
let date = formula.date
let fireDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: -15), to: date as Date)
guard let timeInterval = fireDate?.timeIntervalSince(Date()) else { return }

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: self.timerUserNotificationIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a date 15 minutes bofore a date?

Comment: @Abizern essentially yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you are looking to find a time interval between right now and 15 minutes before some date so that you can fire a notification 15 minutes before that date.

Here's a quick example I knocked up in a playground

```
// Create a date in the future - this is what you get from your own data object and I'm creating it here just so I have a date.
let scheduledDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 09, day: 22, hour: 22))!

// Create a date 15 minutes earlier than your shcheduled date, this is when you want your notification to fire
let fireDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: -15), to: scheduledDate)!

// Then just work out the time interval between the fire date and now to get the time interval
let timeInterval = fireDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())
```

Excuse the force unwrapping of the created dates, these are because it's an example, you should instead not use exclamation marks and handle errors gracefully.

**edited to add**

UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger, which you are trying to use requires a TimeInterval between `now` and the time you want to fire the notification. A TimeInterval is a Double that represents a number of seconds. In some cases, such as this one, it represents a delay, the number of seconds between now and the time you want to fire the the notification. In other cases it represents a date by the number of seconds from a fixed date. This fixed date is either `timeIntervalSince1970` - "The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970." Which is what you use for UNIX timestamps or `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` - "The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001."

Whatever you do, resist the temptation to modify dates by adding or removing numbers of seconds directly, use DateComponents instead.

Comment: I did this but implemented the dates I have and the notification isn't firing

Comment: We can't see what you've done so it's kind of hard to help.

Comment: Have you correctly specified your app's UNNotificationCategory and UNNotificationAction? Because your registration code looks okay.

Comment: I don't want to implement any actions onto a notification, I just simply want the notification to appear

Comment: What are you doing to see if your notification is fired?

Comment: I am creating an appointment in the future and seeing if it fires when it is 15 minutes before the event

Comment: All I have in my AppDelegate is the requestAuthorization method. Do I need something else there? I'm new to using notifications so I have zero clue

Comment: Have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1 ?

Comment: Yes but do I have to implement the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods?

Comment: If your app is in the foreground when the notification arrives, unless you want the notification to be silenced, you do. It's all in the documentation. But this is all beyond the scope of the original question which was about getting the time interval to create the notification's trigger.